# Copy file to other computer using cmd in C#

Tags: c#

I want to copy a picture to homegroup shared folder.
I have opened cmd.exe through *Start Menu > Run > cmd.exe* and typed:

```
copy C:\pic1.png \\SOMECOMP\Users\SOMEONE\Shared
```

The picture has been copied well.
However, when i try to do the same with C#, like that:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cmd.exe", @"/c start copy C:\pic1.png \\SOMECOMP\Users\SOMEONE\Shared");
```

I get the following message:

> Access is denied.

How can i fix this?

P.S. - File.Copy throws the same error. For me, the cmd way looked more promising.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `cmd.exe` to try to run a command instead of just copying the file directly with C#?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

Comment: Why would you use the System.Diagnostics.Process to copy the file, when .NET provides methods for copying files?

Comment: @David Maybe because he didn't really know File.Copy was part of the .Net Framework?

Comment: The same reason - access denied. I have to run this as administrator or what?

Comment: It's a question of the remote machine allowing you to write to the location.  Fix permissions on the remote machine by changing the sharing options.  Administrator won't help if the administrator account on your local machine isn't granted access by the remote machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why on earth would you use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to copy files when there's [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx)?

```
File.Copy(@"C:\pic1.png", @"\\SOMECOMP\Users\SOMEONE\Shared\pic1.png", true);
```

As far as the access denied message is concerned you will need to ensure that the account you are executing your program under has write permissions to this UNC share which might not be the case with ASP.NET applications or Windows NT services which run under limited privileges accounts.

Comment: Yes, OK, are you noticing the `pic1.png` at the end of the dest path argument? Also how about permissions?

Comment: As I said you should grant write permissions to the account you are running your application under. What kind of application is this? Windows, ASP.NET, ...?

Comment: try this. Write the C# app using File.Copy. After building it, do not run it from the IDE. Right click on the executable in the Debug directory adn Run As Admin

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to map the directory

```
& "net" "use" "$mapdrive" "$password" "/USER:$username"
& "copy" $src "$dest"
& "net" "use" $mapdrive "/delete"
```

But yes, if you can, use the System.IO.File namespace to copy the file.